# Detecting child element animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a parent div and inside that there are child divs which are animating left to right. How to detect if any of the child div is animated. The child divs are moving and the left position in the child div styles are changing continuously because they are moving left to right.

```
<div id="products">
<div id="product1 style="color:blue;left:10px;"></div>
<div id="product2 style="color:blue;left:20px;"></div>
<div id="product3 style="color:blue;left:30px;"></div>
</div>
```

The left numbers are changing is there any way to detect the change. Thanks in advance

Comment: how is the animation triggered

Comment: What is causing the change?

Comment: Actually this is an ad and when i upload the html to my company's platform, it ads extra script files to animate my divs. The left position in the child divs changed continuously

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile and didn't test this, but it should work

```
var a = document.getElementById('products').querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var now = a[i].style.left;
    setTimeout(function(){
         if (a[i].style.left != now)
         {
             // the element is animated
         }
    },2);
}
```

Comment: it says script.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Might be because your HTML is invalid. Enclose the Id with ""

Comment: tried updating the code because it is adding extra divs with no style , the error is gone but it just works for the first time and doesnot work when the left property changes if($(a[i]).css('left') == '0'){
  }
  else
  {  console.log("a");
  }

Comment: You can't use jquery on a[i]

Comment: then how to check if some div does not have style property

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. Your div has a style property all the time, whether it's animated or not. But the property for left constantly changes if this property is the one being animated.

Comment: i have pasted the sample version of my html. Some of the divs are added dynamically and some child divs (which are animating) have a left style property which is changing constantly